# keep header with next paragraph in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

Given a document with h2 elements followed by p elements, I some times get a page break between the h2 and the first p, when using wkhtmltopdf.

I have tried:

```
h2 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
    break-after: avoid;
}

h3 + p {
    page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

which I think should avoid page breaks after all h2 elements, and avoid all page breaks before a p element that follows a h2.

Neither of these seem to have any effect. Perhaps I am misusing them.

What does seem to work is `page-break-inside: avoid;`, but that means I have to wrap the header and first paragraph in an element and apply that style to it. Perhaps that is the only solution right now, but it causes me some other problems.

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: A year later, do you happen to know if this situation has changed at all, with wkhtmltopdf? I am hoping they have bumped up their version of WebKit, which would be more likely to support this sort of CSS.

Comment: @halfer I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html

> The current page breaking algorithm of WebKit leaves much to be
>   desired. Basically webkit will render everything into one long page,
>   and then cut it up into pages. This means that if you have two columns
>   of text where one is vertically shifted by half a line. Then webkit
>   will cut a line into to pieces display the top half on one page. And
>   the bottom half on another page. It will also break image in two and
>   so on. If you are using the patched version of QT you can use the CSS
>   page-break-inside property to remedy this somewhat. There is no easy
>   solution to this problem, until this is solved try organising your
>   HTML documents such that it contains many lines on which pages can be
>   cut cleanly.

I think that means `page-break-inside: avoid;` is the only option that works right now (although I am using version 0.12.1.1).